# Would migrating a shared access database to SharePoint be efficient/worth it?

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've recently been hired on as an intern to take over a previous intern's Access 2003 Database. I have no prior experience in Access, and only a fundamental understanding of relational databases/SQL.

I'm looking to make the database faster, and more secure. Right now it's split on the network drive, with the backend database in a subfolder within the main project folder. It's being used by around 70 employees to take tests and store certifications. Several admins use it to create and print these tests.

It's extremely slow. The files are currently stored on a server several states away. If I transferred this database to Sharepoint, would it be faster and more secure? Is it worth the time and effort to do so?

The employees that use this database currently access it from a .exe on their desktop. Would sharepoint be more user friendly for them?

Alternatively, would moving the .mdb files to a closer server solve the speed problem? I'm currently using Access 2010. The forms are painfully slow to use as of right now.

Thank you

Comment: Since the front end is not access what is it written in? Could that be a bottle neck?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the files to a local server would alleviate a lot of the speed concerns.  Moving the file to SharePoint wouldn't do much different in terms of performance.  But I'm assuming the files aren't local already for an unstated reason?  Ideally, it should be moved to MS SQL server if you want to move the database, but that requires MS SQL knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to SharePoint will only work if you up-size the data tables to SharePoint lists.

You cannot place the Access mdb/accDB file on SharePoint in some shared folder and have multiple users update at the same time. The reason of course is SharePoint files cannot accept “partial” writes.  You have to "pull whole" file to client, update, and send whole file back. So this is not a possible setup with Access.

Access requires in multi-user mode that individual users can update “ONLY bits and parts” of the file at the SAME time. When you place a Word or Excel or in this case an Access file on SharePoint then the WHOLE FILE must be downloaded to the client. User then edits and then saves the file back up to SharePoint. So SharePoint is whole document based not file based like windows is. There is no NTFS file system - only a web based up/down file system (very much like FTP).

So SharePoint is a web based interface and Access requires the windows networking system + ALSO the ability to update bits and parts of the file (something SharePoint does not support nor any web site for that matter).

However if you move your back end tables out of Access and up-size the data to SharePoint tables (lists), then the Access front end clients can connect + edit that data. This is not much different in concept of up-sizing the data tables to SQL server.

So Access front ends can connect to an Access back end on a file server (your current setup), or connect to SQL server tables, or connect to SharePoint tables.

I explain how to up-size data tables to SharePoint in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wdjYIby_b0

In some cases Access to SharePoint tables will run absolute circles around Access to SQL server. However in other cases such a setup will run SLOWER then SQL server. Only an experienced Access developer on a case by case basis can determine if SharePoint tables would be appropriate for your application. As the other poster points out adopting SharePoint or SQL server will require experience with those technologies along with likely a few good years of Access experience. Remember Access has a rather long learning curve – in most cases longer then say learning c++

In your case due to the Wide Area Network (WAN), then I suggest terminal services is your best bet.

I explain in easy to grasp terms as to why your setup now is slow in this article and what solutions you can adopt:

http://www.kallal.ca//Wan/Wans.html